# Streaming Audio Using Service

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer

Please take a look at my `simple three-methods Service class` that streams audio and play it directly.

```
public class StreamService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    String url;
    MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");

        mp.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startid) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");

        url = intent.getExtras().getString("url");
        try {
            mp.setDataSource(url);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch(Exception e){}          
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

In my activity, I have two buttons to play/stop the media file:

- The `playButton` execute this:

  ```
  Intent i = new Intent(this, StreamService.class);
  i.putExtra("my_mp3_url_string");
  startService(i);
  ```
- The `stopButton` execute this:

  ```
  stopService(new Intent(this, StreamService.class));
  ```

Now, I have some questions:

1. how I can implement the `pauseButton`? I want to pause the media running in the Service
2. Does my way of playing/stopping the media/Service correct ? Is there any better way?
3. How I can (periodically) update my Activity's UI from my Service? do I need to add something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would recommend not using the lifetime of the Service as a way to start and stop playback. Using that approach will mean that every time you want to start a new stream, the code will be slowed down even more by having to bring up a new Service. You can save some time by just having the same Service play everything. Though that doesn't mean it should remain [running all the time](http://www.androidguys.com/2009/09/09/diamonds-are-forever-services-are-not/).

To accomplish that (and to be able to pause), you'll need to bind to the Service after it is started. With the bound Service, you'll be able to make calls to it - such as pause, play, stop, etc.

Here are some links that should help you with what you're looking for:

- [Using a Service with MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mpandservices)
- [Binding to a Service](http://www.ozdroid.com/#!BLOG/2010/12/19/How_to_make_a_local_Service_and_bind_to_it_in_Android)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Although I'm still straggling in making the Service to update the Activity UI, but I believe you pointed me to the right direction. Thanks again :)

Comment: @iturki: I am working on similar application.can you share your experience about managing player service and UI update in Activity?

Comment: I think there are a couple of options you could go with to update the UI based on changes in the player service. 1. Register a listener when you bind to the player service with a class that you make with callbacks that give you updates about changes in the player service. 2. (probably the easiest method) Use broadcasts from the player service to indicate updates and listen for those broadcasts in your UI.

Comment: It's true that what you said doesn't mean that the service should remain forever.. But, if I can ask for your opinion, how can you apply that to this case? I mean, unless the online stream goes down or the user wants to stop to listen the radio, there is no end for the service.. Right? @Aldryd